# AssertionError while unittesting despite try/except using Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing, and I am trying to test a function that adds two numbers. THe program works fine if I want to test for the right result, but when I want to make the function fail the test, I get an AssertionError although I'm using try/except to catch that exception. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Would someone please point that out?

```
import unittest
import sumXY
from random import randint

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_add(self):
                for a in range(1,5):
                        x = 2
                        y = 3
                        z = 6
                        try:
                                self.assertEqual(sumXY.sum(x,y), z)
                                print "%d + %d = %d" % (x, y, z) + " -> PASSED"
                        except:
                                print "%d + %d = %d" % (x, y, z) + " -> FAILED"
                                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
AssertionError: 5 != 6
```

I would like the output to be: 2 + 3 = 6 -> FAILED

Comment: From what it seems, `except` is nested inside the `try` block. Move the `except` to be on the same level as `try`.

Comment: Actually, everything is properly indented on my script. I couldn't outdent on this site

Comment: Please fix the indentation then. Just paste the code, select it and press `ctrl`/`command` + `k` to mark it as a code block. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more info.

Comment: You should **not** catch `AssertionError`s! They exist so that the `unittest` module knows whether the program failed or not. Also you didn't post the output you got.

Comment: I removed AssertionError so the except is by itself. The output I get is: AssertionError: 5 != 6. The number that the randint generates are x = 2, y = 3, but if you change z to be something else so the test fails, the AssertionError will occur

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting your own `try`...`except` block in the unit test? The whole point of using the `unittest` module is that this kind of machinery is provided for you. Just do something like this:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        for a in range(1,5):
            x = 2
            y = 3
            z = 6
            self.assertEqual(sumXY.sum(x, y), z)
```

If `z` is not equal to `sum(x, y)` then the `unittest` module will display an error. This is the way the framework is intended to be used.

Comment: But how do I display my 'prints' whether the test fails or passes? As you see in my code, I have two print statements. If the test passes when z = 5 it displays: 2 + 3 = 5 -> PASSED. However, if you change z = 6, it should display 2 + 3 = 6 -> FAILED, but it doesn't

Comment: You can make some adjustments to the `unittest` output, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example). If you really want something totally different from what `unittest` provides, though, then you should probably not use that module.